# jdbc to MYSQL error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?user='root'&password=''

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc, sqlexception

I have the following code to connect to a mysql db :

```
public static void insertIntoDatabase(String code,String name,String temp,String hum,String del) {
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        rs = con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS AiportDetails(code VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "name VARCHAR(50), temp VARCHAR(50), hum VARCHAR(50), del VARCHAR(50)) ENGINE=InnoDB;").executeQuery();
        rs = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO AirportDetails(code,name,temp,hum,del) VALUES("+code+","+
                name+","+temp+","+hum+","+del+");").executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**NOTE**  Some common corrections I found online were:

```
1. The driver is not in the /WEB-INF/lib folder.
2. The url is wrong.
```

I dont think this is the case with my code.

 Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can happen if you didn't load the driver before making the first connection ever.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

To be sure, the driver has to go in `/WEB-INF/lib`, not in `/WEB-INF`. You've there by the way some SQL injection holes. Look at `PreparedStatement`. The `finally` can also be improved, as you have it now, the `con` will never be closed when `rs.close()` throws an exception.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry. It is in /WEB-INF/lib folder. and now I am getting a ClassNotFoundException. What could be the problem?